# How to load modules in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I am using pycharm on windows, From where i can remove these error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Charan/PycharmProjects/helloworld/snake.py", line 2, in 
>       import curses
>     File "C:\Users\Charan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\curses__init__.py", line 13, in 
>       from _curses import *
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'

Comment: maybe add the `C:\Users\Python27\site-packages` path to your project interpreter paths.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python on Windows doesn't come with Curses.

You can visit the below link and find the corresponding version(according to your windows and Python installed) to download on your machine. Use PIP to install whl file finally.

[Curses Link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses)

Answer (score 0):

try this 
`pip install windows-curses` 
may be it's work